# How to pass sub-arguments to default function of sub parser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, argparse

If I have an Argparse setup like the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test.')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

parser_somethingX = subparsers.add_parser('somethingX', help='generate X')
parser_somethingY = subparsers.add_parser('somethingY', help="generate Y")

parser_somethingZ = subparsers.add_parser('somethingZ', help='generate Z')
parser_somethingZ.add_argument('N', type=int,help='times to loop')
parser_somethingZ.set_defaults(func=execute_z)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Let's assume a user calls my script with:

```
myScript.py somethingZ 1000
```

What is the correct / best practice way to call my *function execute_z* but also pass it the sub-argument *N* ?

Note that for sub argument *somethingZ* I've set the default function call to be *execute_z*, but how do I pass this function the required followup sub-arguments as well? Namely, *n*? Because the function definition is:

```
def execute_z(n):
  # n is an integer value definining number of times to loop
```

A typical call to my script would be:

```
myScript.py somethingZ 300
```

How do I pass *300* to *somethingZ*?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the `argparse` example using `setdefaults` explained how to use the function?

Look at `args`.  It probably looks something like

```
Namespace(func=execute_z, N=1000)
```

So you should be able to use:

```
args.func(args.N)
```